# Batch File Connecting to Server and execute program install on connected server

Tags: sql, batch-file, cmd

I have been searching for a resolution for days and I am stuck. I've exhausted all resource and need to resolve this. If any one out there with ideas or know how to do this, please help.

I have an SQL Server Database, on Server1. I have an application, which is installed and runs on Server2 (ServerName2) and a procedure that needs to run within an application that is installed on this server.

What I need is to execute the batch file when ever a row get inserted into a table. The SQL Server database is on Server1. The batch file starts an application and calls a script, which executes a procedure. This script needs to run inside an application which is installed on Server2. I have a trigger after insert created on the table. Now I need to some how execute this batch file. Please note, the batch file calls a program which is installed on a different server.

I thought of 2 solutions:

1. To use SQL Server to execute the batch file which sits on Server2. I tried using `"EXEC xp_cmdshell '\\ServerName2\C:\MSTR SCRIPT FILES\Batch_File_Execute_OTB_Script.bat"`.
   It returned 2 records, the first one "The network name cannot be found." and NULL for second one.
2. Create a batch file with a connection string to ServerName2, that Start the .exe program. I am able to get the batch file to start this program and run the script if I run this on ServerName2.

In summary, I need to connect from Server1 to Server2, either through SQL Server or through batch? Is this possible? If yes, please provide me with some guidance.
Once I establish a connection, do I need to call the .exe program and run my script? What is the command to trigger this from remote connection?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, are both servers `SQL Server`? If they are why can't you have linked servers and execute a remote procedure?

Comment: Sorry for the confussion. Both server are running on Windows Server 2008. Server1 has SQL Server Installed. Server2 has my application, MSTR installed.

Comment: Use SQLCMD in batch file.  See SQLCMD /?  I was answering a similar question earlier today and the question got deleted while I was responding.  NT Authentication or SQL Authentication?  Answer and I will reply.

Comment: Thanks RGuggisberg... let me do some research about this..

Comment: As I try to figure out what you are asking... I am not sure SQLCMD is what you are looking for.  SQLCMD will allow you to run SQL queries, SQL scripts, etc from a bat file.  It is not for running bat scripts.

Comment: I just updated my post. I hope it is a little bit more clear.

Comment: I updated my code to show how to run a SQL script.  You may want to then want to save to a temp file and parse the results.

Comment: Thank RGuggisberg. This is very helpful my case doesn't require a connection from batch to SQL server.. I need to establish a connection from SQL Server to my application server. I want to execute the batch everytime i insert into a table. The trick is i need this batch to run on my application server. It requires a program which is install there.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little code to help you connect to the SQL server and interrogate the SQL version.

```
@ECHO OFF
SQLCMD /? > nul 2> nul
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO.SQLCMD not found on this machine & PAUSE & GOTO :eof

SET SQLCmdLine=SQLCMD -b -w400
REM use something like the next line for NT authentication; second line for SQL authentication
REM for NT SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -E -S "YourServerName"
REM for SA SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -U "YourSQLUserName" -P "YourSQLPassword" -S "YourServerName"
SET Database=YourDatabaseName


REM I will use NT Authentication for this example
SET SQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -E -S "(local)"
SET TestSQLCmdLine=%SQLCmdLine% -h-1 -d "%Database%"

REM this will get the SQL version
%TestSQLCmdLine% -Q "SELECT @@VERSION" | FINDSTR /v "rows affected"

REM this will run a SQL script
%TestSQLCmdLine% -i "YourSQLScript.SQL"
PAUSE
```